# how to give plugin edit permission in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

how to give plugin edit permission in WordPress for new user except admin. Is there any plugin to modify or need to customize the existing code

Comment: Can u explain what you are trying to do? What do you want to edit? Posts?

Comment: We are unable to access the website's WordPress plugin to do edit plugin's settings option under editor role for another user.

Answer (score 0):

Install a user capabilities plugin such as [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) and give your non-admin user roles the capability of `manage_options`. However, not all plugin authors follow this rule, and some hard-code for `administrator` role.

Also, be warned, this will give your users access to a lot of the settings functionality that you might not want them to have access to. If that is the case, consider using a more in-depth user plugin such as [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/).